# laravel 5.4 datatables not working jquery $ referenceError

Tags: php, datatables, laravel-5.4

I have this code on my dashboard.index view

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="artists-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Created_at</th>
                        <th>Updated_at</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#artists-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                servedSide: true,
                responsive: true,
                ajax: '{{route('admin.data')}}',
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                    {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                    {data:  'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'}
                ]
            });
        });
```

and this is my dashboardController code

```
class dashboardController extends Controller
{
    //



    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function getIndex(){
        return view('admin.dashboard.index');
    }

    public function getArtists(){
        return Datatables::of(artist::query())->make(true);
    }
}
```

and i have also wrote these two routes, the problem is this is not displaying the data from datatables as ajax only table headings is displayed.
Auth::routes();

```
Route::get('/admin', 'dashboardController@getIndex')->name('admin');
Route::get('/admin.data', 'dashboardController@getArtists')->name('admin.data');
```

this code when I inspect the console I see it displays $ referenceError.

in my admin.blade.php master page I loaded all jquery and assets of datatables. like this as I am using Bootstrap 3.

```
<script src="{{ asset('theme/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('theme/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('theme/js/select2.min.js')}}"></script>
```

at the footer of the master page.

Comment: this means the browser does not recognize `$` in your code so make sure to include the jquery before you use it.

Comment: @AmrAly i edited my question please look again as I added the last section how I added scripts in the master page of admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the [DOM-ready callback](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), i.e.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#artists-table').DataTable({
```

... is being called before the jQuery library has loaded.

The best way to correct this is to include the javascript for your view with a `@yield` blade tag:

Example: `admin.dashboard.index`

```
@section('content')

...

        <table class="table table-striped" id="artists-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Created_at</th>
                    <th>Updated_at</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


...


@endsection

@section('footer_scripts')

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#artists-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                servedSide: true,
                responsive: true,
                ajax: '{{route('admin.data')}}',
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                    {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                    {data:  'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'}
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

And then in your `admin.blade.php` have the area you outlined in your question look something like:

```
...

        @yield('content')

    </div>

    {{-- Scripts --}}
    <script src="{{ asset('theme/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('theme/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('theme/js/select2.min.js')}}"></script>

    @yield('footer_scripts')

</body>
```

Changing to structure above will allow you include javascript in the order you want.

Here are a few examples of what you want to do in action:

- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/usersmanagement/show-users.blade.php
- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/scripts/datatables.blade.php

Comment: @developemator i did as you mentioned and i also removed <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> script and it worked well.